# Listando diretórios "Client" com PHP - Erro quando nome do diretório possui acento

Tags: php, diretório, caracteres

Bom dia.
Estou há pelo menos dois dias tentando encontrar uma solução para o problema que estou enfrentando. Ainda sou novato em php e por isso tanta dificuldade...

Bom, o problema é o seguinte:
Quero criar uma aplicação web para utilizar aqui no TI da empresa. Essa aplicação consiste em navegar por uma estrutura de pastas que irei disponibilizar na rede.
O objetivo final é eu pegar a pasta indicada pelo usuário.
"Mas porque isso?", alguém pode perguntar.
Então a resposta:
O usuário precisa preencher um formulário eletrônico e um dos campos deste formulário consiste em o usuário especificar o caminho completo da pasta onde ele quer acesso. Para que o usuário não precise ficar copiando o caminho pelo Explorer (windows), ele faria isso diretamente pela aplicação,

Bom, consegui implementar a navegação e acabei esbarrando em um problema:
pastas com nomes como "minha pasta é pura ação". Ou seja, pasta com acentuação.

Quando passo este tipo de caminho eu recebo o erro:
 "O sistema n?o pode encontrar o arquivo especificado. (code: 2) in C:\xampp\htdocs\teste\requisicao.php on line 44"

Gostaria da ajuda de alguém para poder sanar esse problema.

Aqui segue o código para quem puder ajudar:
 **index.php**:

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <title>Ajax com jQuery</title>
    <style type="text/css"> #box {border:1px solid #ccc; padding:5px} </style>
</head>
<body>
    <legend>Setor desejado</legend>
    <select id="select_setor" onchange="">
        <option id="null" value="null">Selecione o Setor</option>
        <option id="adm" value="adm">Administrativo</option>
        <option id="com" value="com">Comercial</option>
        <option id="dir" value="dir">Diretoria</option>
        <option id="ope" value="ope">Operacional</option>
        <option id="pro" value="pro">Produtivo</option>
        <option id="qua" value="qua">Qualidade</option>
    </select>
    <div>
        <legend id="raiz">Diretorio: </legend>
        <div id="dir_setor"></div>
    </div>    
    <div>
        <legend>Escolhidos (form com ajax)</legend>
        <div id="box"></div>
    </div>
</body>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#select_setor").change(function(event) {
            $("#null").attr('disabled','disabled');
            var setor = $("#select_setor").val();
            setLegenda();
            $("#dir_setor").load('requisicao.php',{setor:setor},ready());
        });
    });
    function getDir(e) {
        var name = e.name;
        var subs = '//10.40.0.200/Diretorios/Setores/';
        var legenda = "Diretorio: " + name.replace(subs, '');
        document.getElementById('raiz').innerHTML = legenda;
        $("#dir_setor").load('requisicao.php',{diretorio:name},ready());
    }
    function setLegenda(){
        var subs = '//10.40.0.200/Diretorios/Setores/';
        var selected = $('#select_setor :selected').text();
        var legenda = "Diretorio: " + selected.replace(subs, '');
        document.getElementById('raiz').innerHTML = legenda;
    }
    function ready(){}
</script></html>
```

E este é o **requisicao.php**:

```
<?php
ini_set( 'default_charset', 'utf-8');
$setor = (array_key_exists('setor', $_POST) ? $_POST['setor'] : null);
$diretorio = (array_key_exists('diretorio', $_POST) ? $_POST['diretorio'] : null);    
$dirNome = $diretorio;  
if($setor == null){
    $setor = '//10.40.0.200/Diretorios/Setores/';
    $abreDir = $diretorio;
}else{
    $diretorio = '//10.40.0.200/Diretorios/Setores/';
    switch($setor){        
        case 'adm':
            $setor = '//10.40.0.200/Diretorios/Setores/Administrativo/';
        break;

        case 'com':
            $setor = '//10.40.0.200/Diretorios/Setores/Comercial/';   
        break;

        case 'dir':
            $setor = '//10.40.0.200/Diretorios/Setores/Diretoria/';  
        break;

        case 'ope':
            $setor = '//10.40.0.200/Diretorios/Setores/Operacional/'; 
        break;

        case 'pro':
            $setor = '//10.40.0.200/Diretorios/Setores/Produtivo/';
        break;

        case 'qua':
            $setor = '//10.40.0.200/Diretorios/Setores/Qualidade/'; 
        break;        
    }
    $abreDir = $setor;
 }  
$openDir = dir($abreDir);
$tempDir = explode('/', $dirNome);
$backDir = $abreDir;
$indice = count($tempDir) - 2;
if($indice > 2){ $backDir = str_replace($tempDir[$indice].'/', "", $dirNome); }
$table = '';
$table .= '<table id="table_dir" style="border=1px ">';
    while ($arq = $openDir -> read()) {
        if($arq != '.' && $arq != '..'){
            if(is_dir($abreDir.$arq)){
                $arq =      utf8_encode($arq);
                $abreDir =  utf8_encode($abreDir);
                $table .= '<tr>';
                $table .= '<td>';
                $table .= $arq;
                $table .= '</td>';
                $table .= '<td><a name="';
                $table .= $abreDir.$arq;
                $table .= '/" href="#" class"href_dir" onclick="getDir(this)"> Abrir </a></td>';

                $table .= '</tr>';
            }else{
                if(strpos('~$', $arq)){
                    echo '<tr>';    
                    echo '<td>'.$arq.'</td>';
                    echo '<td> -- </td>';
                    echo '</tr>';
                }

            }
        }
    }
$table .= '</table>';
echo $table;
if ($abreDir != $setor) { echo '<td><a name="'.$backDir.'" href="#" class"href_dir" onclick="getDir(this)"> Voltar </a></td>'; }
$openDir->close(); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Para resolver o problema eu alterei:

```
$openDir = dir($abreDir);
```

Para:

```
$openDir = dir(utf8_decode($abreDir));
```

Desculpa eu mesmo responder a minha pergunta, mas é que pelo que eu li no "help" do stackoverflow eu preciso votar em uma resposta para que minha pergunta seja respondida.